# Moment.js comparing to times range with am pm

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an dates array which has an array of appointment times in each date. I loop through a given date to get the appointment times like this :

```
var newdate = moment(appdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); //eg newdate is 04/04/2016
var newtime = moment(apptime).format('h:mm a');

appointmentArr[newdate].forEach(function(value, key) {
        console.log(value); //these are all the appointment times for 04/04/2016 eg 11:22:00 AM     
});
```

My question is, how can i check with moment.js, if "newtime" and "value" are within XX mins of each other? ive looked in the docs and on other posts but cant get it right with the AM PM formatting i am using.

Comment: Change them to date objects with the same year, and subtract them (should return time in seconds)? Sorry, I'm not very good with Date objects.

Comment: Cant it comes from the database as just 11:20:00 am for example, theres no date

Comment: I just need to work out the diff between say, 10:20:00 AM and 11:20:00 PM

Comment: I'm saying you could convert it to a date.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two dates with MomentJS you can use `moment.diff`, and you can specify the unit of measure you want your result in:

```
newDate.diff(oldDate, 'minutes');
```

You can then compare that value with your threshold and profit!

EDIT: But you should **not** format the date *before* comparing it, since `format` returns a string. Keep your `moment` object intact, and format it whenever you need to display it (or save the formatted string in another variable).

Comment: The time is coming from a legacy access database so all i can get is '11:00 AM'

Comment: Then you need to specifiy the format you are trying to parse in the `moment` method call, for example `newtime = moment('11:00 AM', 'h:mm a')`. The date will be set to today, but it shouldn't matter if you just need to `diff` the time. [The Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)